# Not able to redirect from a dynamic route to any other route of page folder in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

I have some routes in my next.js application like

```
worksheets\[grade]\[subject].js 
wokrsheets.js
```

but when i am using **route.push** method from worksheets.js its perfectly redirecting me to **Login** page

```
router.push("/login");
```

but when i am using same push method from **dynamic** route its not redirecting and throwing this error

```
Error: The provided `href` (/student/worksheets/[grade]/[subject]) value is missing query values (grade, subject) to be interpolated properly.
```

Read more: https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/href-interpolation-failed

even after I am using query in my dynamic url object in **Link** component

```
<Link
  href={{
       pathname: `worksheets/[grade]/[subject]`,
       query: { grade: gradeInfo.grade, subject: subject },
  }}
 >
</Link>
```

what i am doing wrong ??

Comment: Are you sure that `gradeInfo.grade` and `subject` values are not undefined?

Comment: yes its not undefined

Comment: The [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/href-interpolation-failed) states that somewhere you are utilizing the `next/link` component, `Router#push`, or `Router#replace` with href interpolation to build dynamic routes but did not provide all of the needed dynamic route params to properly interpolate the href.

Comment: I have used a query object in the URL object, used `query: { grade: gradeInfo.grade, subject: subject },` in all the Link component where i am using dynamic routing but not working

Answer (score 0):

The error message "The provided href value is missing query values to be interpolated properly" occurs when using the Link component from Next.js and not providing the required query parameters for proper interpolation.

To resolve this issue, you need to update the pathname and as values in the Link component to include the necessary query parameters.

Here's an example of how you can fix this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

function ExampleComponent({ gradeInfo, subject }) {
    const href = "/worksheets/[grade]/[subject]";
    const as = `/worksheets/${gradeInfo.grade}/${subject}`;

    return (
        <Link href={href} as={as}>
            <a>Go to Worksheets</a>
        </Link>
    );
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

Comment: No, it's not working , I have tried it